# Install package using pip from git into site-packages

Tags: python, git, pip, python-import

I installed a Python package using pip from git. In order to achieve this, I added the command
`-e git+<link>#<egg>` to my requirements.txt. Pip installs this package, but not in the way I would like to have it.

First problem: I use a virtual environment. Usually, packages end up in `<env>/Lib/site-packages`. This one does not, it ends up in `<env>/src`. This makes it more to difficult to import.

Second problem: The `src` folder also gets created within my actual project, the one I am working on.

Both things are different to installing packages from other sources like PyPI. Is there a way to install my own packages via git in the same way? I actual built a wheel and a tar.gz, but I don't know how to install them ...

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` in your project? If not, please checkout [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Which project do you mean? The one I want to import using git or the one I am working on? I have a setup.py and used setuptools to build the wheel and the sdist.

Comment: you should end up with a `pkgname.egg-link` and an `easy-install.pth` file in site-packages -- it *is* installed into site-packages, just via some pth hackery (due to the editable install via `-e`)

Comment: @AnthonySottile you are right, I found the files you listed in site-packages. I never notices them before. But how does this help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AnthonySottile's comment pointed me into the right direction: The `-e` option makes the installed package editable, which is not what I wanted. It actually works without it!
So if you want to avoid having `src` folders appearing everywhere - download from git without the -e option:
`git+<link>#<egg>`

Unfortunately, I didn't find any documentation for this ... so feel free to post a more profound answer or add to this one.

Answer (score 0):

The following format of specifying a git+https location in requirements.txt worked for me:

```
pycocotools@git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

But I had to install `numpy` and `Cython` first, so that the installation of that package was successful. `setuptools` was already installed, this might need attention too.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\project> pip install -r requirements.txt
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com, https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
Collecting pycocotools@ git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
  Cloning https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git (to revision cocodataset-master) to c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ofosrylu\pycocotools_6c865fdd5be947bdaed6b1bb6e7ec022
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ofosrylu\pycocotools_6c865fdd5be947bdaed6b1bb6e7ec022'
  Running command git checkout -b cocodataset-master --track origin/cocodataset-master
  Branch 'cocodataset-master' set up to track remote branch 'cocodataset-master' from 'origin'.
  Switched to a new branch 'cocodataset-master'
# ... output of other packages
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  Building wheel for pycocotools (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pycocotools: filename=pycocotools-2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=82226 sha256=4fcb72a83132367541d71faa8f0fb5a838e910c017f9aa033d13c19aebaada61
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-_ygd_748\wheels\a6\5f\ec\1eaf8c69abab5724baee819736e6d30adad774deb60736413b
Successfully built pycocotools
```