# Pip install only installs top-level Python file in package

Tags: python, git, pip

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904632/install-package-using-pip-from-git-into-site-packages).

I want to install and use a Python package/library that I created in a git repo. It gets installed and I can access it, BUT: Only the Python file at the package's top level is installed in `<env>/Lib/site-packages`. There are subfolders in the git repo, but I don't see them in my site-packages and when I try to access them I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<package_name>.<subfolder>'`.

How can I install ALL CONTENT of my library?

I tried using wheel and setup.py. This is supposed to mean that I included both a wheel and a tar.gz in my repo and I installed it without having package wheel installed and with having package wheel installed. Result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the missing files were also not present in the generated .tar.gz of my library.

I found the answer, the error was my misunderstanding of **setup.py**.
In its **packages** option I only gave the top-level source directory name and assumed it would be interpreted recursively. But this does not seem to be the case. Instead, use `setuptools.find_packages()` for exactly this job. See the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) for more of its options.